# How to print outputstream PDF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I'm getting PDF file as **output stream** and want to print it using **Javascript**. There're some tips about printing PDF file or iframe. But I need to print PDF files that is generated by server after print request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can't access any local resources like the file system or attached printers, so this isn't possible directly.

What you need is to convert the PDF to, say, HTML5. Then display that in your browser and call `document.print()` to print it.

The project [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) already does a pretty good job to convert PDF to HTML.